# Delete grouped rows from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 48503 rows. The dataframe has multiple user ids who can make multiple simulations or just one and the only way to tell is by looking at the time difference between the simulations that the user did. If this difference in time is over 20 secs long then we assume that the guy then the simulations where done in different sessions.

I want to make a new column with the session number of the simulation for each user

```
(ID) (Simulation Number) (Simulation-time-difference)  (Session)

 A         1                0:00:00.00                1
 A         2                0:00:08.22                1
 A         3                0:00:20.67                2
 A         4                0:00:05.38                2
 B         5                0:00:00.00                1
 B         6                0:00:03.32                1
 B         7                0:00:28.45                2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method using `ave` and `cumsum` after extracting the seconds:

```
# extract the seconds
df$seconds <- as.numeric(gsub("^0:00:([0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2})", "\\1", df$V3))
# calculate the session number
df$session <- ave((df$seconds > 20), df$V1, FUN=cumsum) + 1
```

This produces the desired output.

```
df
  V1 V2         V3 seconds session
1  A  1 0:00:00.00    0.00       1
2  A  2 0:00:08.22    8.22       1
3  A  3 0:00:20.67   20.67       2
4  A  4 0:00:05.38    5.38       2
5  B  5 0:00:00.00    0.00       1
6  B  6 0:00:03.32  1    3.32       1
7  B  7 0:00:28.45  2   28.45       2
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text=" A         1     0:00:00.00              
A         2                0:00:08.22              
A         3                0:00:20.67              
A         4                0:00:05.38              
B         5                0:00:00.00              
B         6                0:00:03.32   
B         7                0:00:28.45", as.is=TRUE)
```